# onClick on stacked components

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I have two react arrow function components stacked on top of each other (using absolute positioning) and both of them have onClick attributes. The problem is, I want to click on the one that is on top, and both onClick functions trigger. Is there anyway to work around this?

This is a simplified version of the code:

```js
const Card = ({...}) => {

    const styles = {
        optionsButton: {
            minWidth:0,
            minHeight: 0,
            padding: "2px",
            position: "absolute",
            color: "#808080",
            zIndex: 1,
            right: 5,
            top: 5,
            '&:hover':{
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
            }
        },
    }

    const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(false)
    const [isCardExpanded, setIsCardExpanded] = useState(false)

    const expandCard = () => {
        setIsCardExpanded(true)
    }
    const closeCard = () => {
        setIsCardExpanded(false)
    }


    const mainPaperStyle = () => {
        let style = {
            padding: "10px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            position: "absolute",
            "&:hover": {
                filter: "brightness(97%)"
            }
        }

        //Extra code here modifying color of the style, no positioning modifications

        return style
    }

    const buttonAction = () => {
        console.log("Do action!")
    }

    return(
        <>
            <Paper sx={mainPaperStyle()} onClick={expandCard} onMouseEnter={() => setHovering(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHovering(false)}>
                Lorem Ipsum

                {hovering &&
                    <Button variant="filled"
                            id="card-button"
                            sx={styles.optionsButton}
                            onClick={() => buttonAction()}>
                        <MoreVertIcon/>
                    </Button>
                }
            </Paper>
        </>
    )
}
```

And here is a screenshot of why I want two components stacked on top of each other:

- Before hovering:
  [image: Before hover]
- After hovering:
  [image: After hover]

I want a Button to appear when hovering on top of the Paper component. The problem is, when I click the button, both `expandCard` and `buttonAction` trigger. (I am using Material UI btw)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Sure, one sec @MostafaElkaramany

Comment: And share a screenshot please, I don't get why you need 2 components on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation();`.

```
const firstFn = () => { // first function body };
const secondFn = (event: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => { 
    $event.stopPropagation();
    // second function body
}
```

So in your case you need to change function `buttonAction` to this

```
const buttonAction = (event) => {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Do action!")
}
```

and return clause with

```
return(
        <>
            <Paper sx={mainPaperStyle()} onClick={expandCard} onMouseEnter={() => setHovering(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setHovering(false)}>
                Lorem Ipsum

                {hovering &&
                    <Button variant="filled"
                            id="card-button"
                            sx={styles.optionsButton}
                            onClick={() => buttonAction($event)}>
                        <MoreVertIcon/>
                    </Button>
                }
            </Paper>
        </>
    )
```

You can learn about this more in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: I am afraid this has not worked. The expandCard function is still triggering even with the `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that. Can you post a JSFiddle with your full code? So we can check it there what's the issue is

Comment: Hey, I mistakenly added $event.preventDefault() with $event.stopPropagation();. I've updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: Hey I just asked a coworker as he passed by and recomended that! I was going to post the answer and saw that you modified it hahaha. Props on getting it right in the end. Thank you!